# Serenity framework Same form in tabs

Tags: javascript

How would I get the same form in different tabs, by groups. My table is too large so I would like to section them to tabs, I don't see an applicable demo.
I would also like to be able to link a notes table by ID, similar to the Customer tab here.

[image]

Comment: first, try something to do by yourself, if u face any problem ,then post with the problems you are facing .
Nobody is going to help you if u deny to help yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to know this, here you go:-
There is a demo after all, and it's in Northwinds, under 'Order', it's really easy, I just hadn't seen it before. You just put that in myTableForms.cs where you want it, and that's it! Awesome.

```
    [Tab("General")]
    [Category("Order")]
```

I didn't see it there cause it wasn't there last week!

Comment: from serenity ver 3.0.7 you can use Tab attribute.
https://github.com/volkanceylan/Serenity/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#307-2017-10-07